# What does the `transpile` option do?

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js, babeljs

In NuxtJS, in the configuration file, you can pass a `transpile` option. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#transpile
I don't see it impacting the final webpack file.

What does it do?

Comment: @kissu my main issue is that the transpiled code doesnt seem to respect the presets/browsers that you mentioned in your reply https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/10465

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the package or the browsers you're targeting (older versions of IE for example), you may want to use Babel to transpile that into an ES5 bundle.

Most of the time it's not needed but some package require it. On top of that, the system tends to use ESM for everything so you will not use that often.

Comment: I use babel with `preset-env` and the `browserslist` config option, any idea what takes precedence there? (why is there a separate config option in Nuxt)

Comment: Usually you don't need to bother with a Babel config while using Nuxt, hence you can simply pass it in the nuxt configuration. If you have your own custom Babel transpilation step, you could omit the one from Nuxt. Still, some packages need to be transpiled for dev sometimes, so it can be handy in that case. But if you're comfortable writing your own, feel free to do that only! @GeorgeKatsanos

Comment: Nuxt is mainly trying to improve the whole DX by doing some stuff for you and not asking you to do the hard/boring work. It can be "magic" sometimes but it's not always the most optimal thing if you want to have a really custom + precise and bleeding edge configuration for example.

Comment: This is my case; I'd like to tweak the defaults and optimize my build...

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos you can skip the config from Nuxt so.